# File upload request sent empty in React / Laravel application using api

Tags: reactjs, laravel, upload

We are building an application that uses React framework for the frontend and Laravel framework for the backend. The problem is whenever sending a post request for `'/store-image'` route. The response returns with `Error 500: Call to a member function storeAs() on null`.
It seems that Laravel isn't reading the request.
Here is my request code:

```
const formDa = new FormData();
setSelectedFile(imgRef.current.files[0]);
    formDa.append("file", selectedFile);
    fetch("https://api.pharo-tech.xyz/store-image",{
      method:'POST',
      body : {
        image : formDa,
      },
      headers : {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=> console.log(data)).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Here is my ImageController.php code:

```
 public function store(Request $request) {
     $request->file('image')->storeAs('profile_images', mt_rand(100, 1000000000) . ".{$request->file('image')->guessExtension()}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You append `formDa.append("file", selectedFile);`and from API you try to get file `$request->file('image')`. Here your attach file stored in file not image.

You need to update your code as below.

HTML

```
<input type="file" onchange="onLoadImage(this)">
```

Script

```
function onLoadImage(e) {
        var token = '';
        var selectedFile = e.files[0];

        const formDa = new FormData();
        formDa.append("image", selectedFile);

        fetch("https://api.pharo-tech.xyz/store-image", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formDa,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(data =>
            console.log(data)).catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
```

API

```
 public function store(Request $request) {
     $request->file('image')->storeAs('profile_images', mt_rand(100, 1000000000) . ".{$request->file('image')->guessExtension()}");

     return response()->json([success: true]);
}
```

Comment: Nope! That doesn't change anything....

Comment: Are you trying to with the updated code?

Comment: Yes, That doesn't change anything

Comment: Sorry, there was some issue with my code. I hope, Now the updated code work perfectly.